# Resolving second case collisions using Double Hashing

Tags: data-structures, hash, hashtable, collision, double-hashing

When provided with a second collision case, how is this resolved?

I.E:

Let's say we have an array of numbers:

[22, 1, 13, 11, 24, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]

Where -1 indicates empty in the array....

if we were to attempt to insert 33 using

```
h1(key) = key % 11
h2(key) = 7 - (key % 7)
```

Passing in 33 would give 2, where the array location 2 is already occupied (with 13). How do we handle this collision case? Do we pass the returned mod value into h2 again? Do we replace the value @ that array value? (I suspect the latter is not the case.)

Edit: Added parenthesis to h2

Comment: Did you try the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) for a start? There is a number of possibilities outlined. If there's still a question, please make it more specific than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With double hashing, you compute the position as:

```
pos = (h1 + i * h2) mod table_size
```

The trick here is to increment `i` until an empty position in the hash table is found. Therefore the computation is not only done once, but multiple times until a slot has been found. See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_hashing) for details.

There are other forms of open addressing similar to double hashing that are very efficient too, for example [cuckoo hashing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuckoo_hashing) and [robin-hood hashing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Robin_Hood_hashing).